# Symfony/doctrine: Optimize n+1 queries

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, eager-loading

### Context

Imagine a set of proposals, where every user can vote up or down for a proposal.

So I have 2 models:

- A `Proposal`,
- A `Vote`, related to a `proposal`, a `user`, and an `opinion` (up or down).

Now I want to display all my proposals, including extra information for each proposal:

- How many upvotes ?
- How many downvotes ?
- Has the current user upvoted ?
- Has the current user downvoted ?

### Issue

This is really easy to implement, but this implies 4 request per proposal display (called the n+1 query issue).
I come from Rails world, where this can easily be resolved using eager loading or some tricky queries. But I can not resolve it with doctrine and need some help!

### What I tried

#### Use magical fields

The first solution is to make a custom query: select all the proposal, including the number of upvotes, downvotes, has the current user upvoted or downvoted.

The query now returns 4 more columns than the model describe: `count_upvotes`, `count_downvotes`, `has_user_upvoted` and `has_user_downvoted`.

To be useable with doctrine, I have to add these field to my `Proposal` Entity.

For me, this is not a good solution, because it implies to always use this query to avoid bastard model, where these fields can be null.

#### Use a summary

The second solution is to make another object to be used by the view. This object is created with an argument: the current user. This object is created by optimized queries, and contains these methods:

- `getAllProposals()`
- `getUpvotes($a_proposal)`
- `getDownvotes($a_proposal)`
- `hasUserUpvoted($a_proposal)`
- `hasUserDownvoted($a_proposal)`

For me, it's really overkilled to be forced to create an object just for a view optimization.

#### Use extended Entity

This third solution use an unique query to get proposals, their upvotes, downvotes, and check if user has up or downvoted.

It creates a new "extended" entity,

```
public function __construct(
    Proposal $badgeProposal,
    $upvotesCount,
    $downvotesCount,
    $hasUserUpvoted,
    $hasUserDownvoted
) {
```

For me, this is the better solution, but for the moment this can not work because I don't know how to simply hydrate a Proposal from a SQL row (but I'm searching hardly).

#### Your turn

So, what can be other solutions? Is has to be a well-known issue for doctrine developers.

Answer (score 7):

Have you already experimented on this or just thought about it?

For me, a simple `fetch="EAGER"` solved this, resulting in exactly one query. With the following setup

```
class Proposal {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="proposals", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $votes;
}

class Vote {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Proposal", inversedBy="votes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(..)
     */
    protected $proposal;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Opinion", inversedBy="votes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(..)
     */
    protected $opinion;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="votes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(..)
     */
    protected $user;
}

class Opinion/User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="proposals")
     */
    protected $votes;
}
```

Actually, I edited the `Proposal` entity even more, adding the following methods

```
class Proposal {
    public function getCountOpinion($id) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($this->getVotes() as $vote) {
            if ($vote->getOpinion()->getId() === $id) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }

    public function getUserVote($user) {
        foreach ($this->getVotes() as $vote) {
            if ($vote->getUser() == $user) {
                return $vote;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the beginning, this still resulted in only one query. However, you see alot of `for` here. If you have lots of votes for each proposal, you might want to cache the results (eg. iterating over votes only once, getting all the countOpinion and userVote)

PS: Don't forget to add constructors for the classes that have ArrayCollections (OneToMany)

Comment: Hi @kero ! Very interesting proposal. This worked like a charm. I think a negative point of your method is that we hydrate all the Vote entities, even if we never used it, because we only "count" it. But very interesting btw.

Comment: You are right. I guess another solution would be to write a custom query using DQL, working with `SUM` etc