# How to not multiply request in symfony when using association table

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a trouble with symfony.
I have three table in my database :
Musicien, Composer and Oeuvre
Composer is an association table between Musicien and Oeuvre.

When I load a page who show a Musicien, it show his Oeuvres.
So I make a join between Musicien and Composer, and between Composer and Oeuvre.
From a Musicien I can get all his composer with one request. But, to show his Oeuvres, I need to loop on his Composers to get all Oeuvres.
It makes one request by get, so if I have n Composer it will makes n request.
It is horribly slow.

I want to make it with one request, but I don't know how to do that, can you help me ?
Maybe if I make the join between Musicien and Oeuvre directly, but I don't know how to do that too.

Thank you.

This is my code :

Musicien:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Musicien
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Musicien", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_AC6BE67520B77BF2", columns={"Code_Pays"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_AC6BE675E1990660", columns={"Code_Genre"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_AC6BE675D389A975", columns={"Code_Instrument"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Musicien
{
    /* Some attributes here*/
    /**
     * @var \Composer
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Composer", mappedBy="codeMusicien")
     */
    private $composer;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->oeuvres = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    public function getOeuvres()
    {
        $oeuvres = new ArrayCollection();
        $oeuvres->add($this->composer->getCodeOeuvre());
        // foreach($this->composer as $c){
        //     $oeuvres->add($c->getCodeOeuvre());
        // }
        return $oeuvres;
    }

}
```

Composer

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Composer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Composer", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_6105648EE694D5AB", columns={"Code_Musicien"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_6105648ECB48FCBD", columns={"Code_Oeuvre"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Composer
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Code_Composer", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $codeComposer;

    /**
     * @var \Musicien
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Musicien", inversedBy="composer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Code_Musicien", referencedColumnName="Code_Musicien")
     * })
     */
    private $codeMusicien;

    /**
     * @var \Oeuvre
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Oeuvre", inversedBy="composer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Code_Oeuvre", referencedColumnName="Code_Oeuvre")
     * })
     */
    private $codeOeuvre;

    public function getCodeComposer(): ?int
    {
        return $this->codeComposer;
    }

    public function getCodeMusicien(): ?Musicien
    {
        return $this->codeMusicien;
    }

    public function setCodeMusicien(?Musicien $codeMusicien): self
    {
        $this->codeMusicien = $codeMusicien;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeOeuvre(): ?Oeuvre
    {
        return $this->codeOeuvre;
    }

    public function setCodeOeuvre(?Oeuvre $codeOeuvre): self
    {
        $this->codeOeuvre = $codeOeuvre;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Oeuvre

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Oeuvre
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Oeuvre", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_32522BC898F61075", columns={"Code_Type"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Oeuvre
{
    /**
     * Some attributes here
     */

    /**
     * @var \Composer
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Composer", mappedBy="codeOeuvre")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Composer")
     */
    private $composer;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->musiciens = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getMusiciens()
    {
        $musiciens = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach($this->composer as $c){
            $musiciens->add($c->getCodeMusicien());
        }
        return $musiciens;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can read up on [lazy loading here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-object-graph-traversal).  And then write yourself a DQL query to use eager loading.

Comment: You can avoid using a third class for `ManyToMany` by using https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional and creating an auxiliar table.

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497843/symfony-doctrine-optimize-n1-queries